# Using XmlHttpRequest to fetch webpage

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm sorry for the vague title. I'm not quite sure how to word it.

I am fairly new to programming and working on a small chrome extension that checks a particular website for new product listings. I am retrieving the webpage using XmlHttpRequest, however I would like to get the webpage with certain display options already applied.

The webpage I am fetching uses javascript to change its display options. By default, it shows only in-stock items and 20 items. What I want is both in-stock and out-of-stock, and 100 items.

If I go to the website and directly change the options, then fetch the page with XmlHttpRequest, it will return what I want. But I would like to be able to do this all from within the program.

This is the webpage: http://ekizo.mandarake.co.jp/shop/en/category-action-figure.html

Any idea if this is possible and if so, how I could accomplish it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: All of those settings are stored in the `search_option` cookie,

Comment: So in my program, I would just need to locate and edit the search_option cookie file right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at what happens when you change the number of items to display it goes to this page with the added variables:

http://ekizo.mandarake.co.jp/shop/en/searchOption.do?action=setListCount&keyword=&searchStrategy=keyword&listCount=100

All you need to do is recreate that GET request with the details you want.
(although for the other things such as stock avaliability I have not looked as to where this is)

[Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) is your friend with this kind of thing.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Chrome just shows the original url when I set the options so I didn't catch that.